# Qt (C++): Get QProcess stdout and stderr separately

Tags: c++, qt, stdout, stderr, qprocess

I want to get the stderr of a QProcess (ideally as a QIODevice), but I can't figure out how. Another thread is reading from stdout using the methods QProcess inherits from QIODevice, so `QProcess::MergedChannels` and `QProcess::setReadChannel(...)` are out of the question. `QProcess::readAllStandardError()` is also not ideal.

Comment: what's not ideal about them? Except miguiding names that those may actually read not all output.

Answer (score 2):

You have to connect some slot to `readyReadStandardError()` signal of QProcess to read data by `QProcess::readAllStandardError()` and be store it for concatenation, in addition to `finished()` signal to make concluding calls, similar to how you would do that for standard output.

```
connect(&process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(readErrData()));
connect(&process, SIGNAL(finished(int , QProcess::ExitStatus)), 
         this, SLOT(finalizeProcessTask(int , QProcess::ExitStatus)));
```